# Tiny default image is showing instead of the image i sourced

Tags: html

all that's popping up is a little tiny default pic. I want the picture that I sourced image1.jpg to be showing. Spent ages looking for the error so I thought I'd ask. www.shaunstanley.co.uk it's on the portfolio page. 
So i am pretty certain i have checked the pathways but i'm pretty bad at coding so any help would be fantastic

Comment: provide your efforts to solve issue

Comment: Please edit your question to limit what you want to ask. I cannot understand what you want to do exactly!

Comment: I just want the image to show and it's not and I don't know why or how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The 'Tiny Default Image' is displayed when the image cannot be found where you linked it to.

To fix this, check that you have uploaded the image into http://www.shaunstanley.co.uk/sub-pages/image1.jpg

It looks like you only have the following files in the 'sub-pages' folder:
about.html, contact.html, exhibitions.html and portfolio.html

Next time, use the 'Inspect' menu on your web browser to find the problem - right click and inspect. In the console, you will see the problem. In this case, it says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)